# Url parameters Reporting Services

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I need sending to c# application a parameter with a Url. So I need specify the url, the problem is says "have not a token sintax valid."

[image: I need sending to c# application a parameter with a Url. So I need specify the url, the problem is says "have not a token sintax valid."]

http://www.inec.go.cr/sgapaweb/encuesta/wfrEncuestaTrimestral.aspx?modalidad=2&Id_Boleta=[Numero_Boleta]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make an expression from the url. Use the Fx btn after the textbox.

In the popup you can edit the url and add variables to the string.